# Need to update Lead executive (Lookup with User) field based on the odd or even value of Lead_number__c(auto number external Id) field

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am looking to change the Lead_Executive field on Lead object(Lookup field with User) if the Lead_number__c(auto number field) is Odd or even. if the Lead_number__c is odd, then Lead_Executive will be User1 and if Lead_number__c is even, then Lead_Executive will be User2.

Comment: Can you also share what you have tried so far and what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Thanks for your response.

It's working fine now. I changed the lead number from L-{00000} to just {00000} and then created a new field in which i am storing the odd and even values. After that in the Lead trigger, using the newly created field of odd and even in if condition, I assigned the Lead_executive__c with the user id and its working fine. 

If there would be problem in executing further requirements on the above task, I'll let you know.

Thanks again!